# Use javascript AND PHP in one <input> tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I feel like I've looked around for the answer for this question, but most of the responses are very hacky: involving javascript that pops in via AJAX, redirects and other ways of modifying the DOM on the fly.

What I want to do is make the submit button disappear when a user submits a document (javascript) and submit the message via mail (php). The code I have is the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
...
<input onclick="removeElements()" id="subButton" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

The php mail function is in the same document.

Here is the removeElements() function:

```
var el = document.getElementById("subButton");
el.remove();
document.getElementById("thankYouMessage").setAttribute("style", "display:block");
```

The submit function works without the javascript call, but when I add the **onclick="removeElements()"** part, then the javascript part starts working, but the php is no longer executed.

I know that there are other methods for doing this, but in this case, I'm actually curious about why this doesn't function as I had planned. By removing the submit button, am I in effect killing the child PHP process mid(or pre)-execution?

Thanks!

Comment: because you just remove the Dom so there is no submit event ? If so, I think change `el.remove();` to `el.style.display="none"` for a test.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that I tried all of these css tricks to disable the visibility of the id. They don't work. I feel like they remove the button, but then it just comes back fractions of a second later.
So the button doesn't disappear and the email isn't sent. I'll look at it more to see if I can update the above with more relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `onclick` you will have to fire the submit manually.

The other option is add your javascript call code in `onsubmit="removeElements()"` on the form tag. This way, it will execute your code after executing submit

Related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839459/submit-and-onclick-not-working-together)

Comment: I like this - I didn't know about the onsubmit event listener. I felt like this was progress, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove the button, rather set `visible: hidden` or `display: none` for its style. This way it will still be in the document and will work, it just won't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the form reloads your page so I suggest:

- Using Ajax and only delete button on the response, or
- Not generate the button when reloads your page.

Jquery Ajax examples: You can see them here [api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use the `.hide` functionality which JQuery gives you. It's very simple to use and very clean.

**Example1 using JQuery:**

```
$("#FormID").submit(function(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
   // Hide button
   $("#subButton").hide();
   // Display thank-you message
   $("#thankYouMessage").css("display", "block");
});
```

**Example2 using JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
       $("#subButton").hide();
       $("#thankYouMessage").css("display", "block");
       return false;
    });
});
```