# programatically click on button using javascript

Tags: javascript

on a webpage there is a "show more" button when I click inspect element appears

```html
<input name="" id="" onclick="GetComments();" class="showMore showMoreNew" value=" المزيد" type="submit">
```

I want to click it using JavaScript

Comment: Where is your `GetComments()` function?

Comment: Just invoke `GetComments();` function...

Comment: If you want to programmatically execute a click event, you can use `$('.showMore.showMoreNew').trigger('click')`

Comment: I see that you’ve got an `onclick` handler on a `type="submit"` button. Therefore, this is related: [Submit and onclick not working together](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13839459/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used

```
document.getElementsByClassName("showMoreNew")[0].click();
```

and it works.

Answer (score -2):

JQuery solution not work under certain condition, below solution always works.

```
document.getElementById("xxx").click();
```

Comment: Except when the element has no id attribute

Comment: it seems the OP does not have control of the source code of the page. He can't add an id unless he were to add it through JS or through the developer console. If through JS, he'd have to select it first and if through the developer console, it's more work than just using a different selector. (Also, if using the console, your answer would need to explain how to do that before it works)