# php $_REQUEST[ ] dosnt work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have form in html file , it's file body

```
<form action="" method="post">       
    <input id="name" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required></br></br>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></br></br>
    <p id="warn"></p></br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="f()"></br>
</form>

<script>
function f() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value ;
    var xttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("warn").innerHTML = this.responseText ;             
        }
    };

    xttp.open("GET", "tst1.php?name="+name+"& password"+password, true);
    xttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and i have php file callled tst1.php

```
<?php 
    echo $_REQUEST["name"]+"...."+$_REQUEST["password"] 
?>
```

im trying to use ajax to show the entered value below them in p tag with id="warn"
but it dose not show it

Comment: You are submitting your form at the same time you do your Ajax call. Your page refreshes before you can see if it actually works or not.

Comment: Question is not clear enough to give a good answer. What have you done to debug? What are you seeing passed back in your console net tab?

Comment: Also you can't close a `<br>`tag. (`</br>` is invalid)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit and onclick not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839459/submit-and-onclick-not-working-together)

Comment: @ivar thanks. how can i solve refresh problem ?

Comment: @mamad Rajdeep has that as part of his answer.

Comment: @ivar yes ! THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in your code, such as:

- `echo $_REQUEST["name"]+"...."+$_REQUEST["password"]`, `+` is not a concatenation operator, `.` is. So this statement should be like this:

  ```
  echo $_REQUEST["name"] . "...." . $_REQUEST["password"];
  ```
- Missing `=` sign after `password` in this statement, `xttp.open("GET", "tst1.php?name="+name+"& password"+password, true);`. This statement should be like this:

  ```
  xttp.open("GET", "post.php?name="+name+"&password="+password, true);
  ```
- Return `false` immediately after calling `f()` function, otherwise the page would refresh and you won't be able to see the output value here `<p id="warn"></p>`.

  ```
  <input ... onclick="f(); return false;">
  ```

Comment: thanks for solving problem and sorry for stupid mistakes , could you plain explain me what that return false do ? dose it stop the form to be submitted or ... ? @Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @mamad What `return false;` will do is, it will prevent the form from being submitted in the first place. That way you'll be able to see the output here, `<p id="warn"></p>`. Also, consider *accepting* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: sorry im new to web developing  , what is common way to have a login page ? i want to check the entered values in my database if there is user show his homepage if not show error ? is it ajax good for this purpose ?can you plz give me some advice ?  @ Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @mamad You can start off with some [AJAX tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started). And on top of that, you would fine plenty of tutorials on Google on [how to implement a simple login page using JavaScript/jQuery and AJAX](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=implement+login+page+using+ajax&oq=implement+login+page+using+ajax&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2327.2327.0.2555.1.1.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.e7qLEaW9eqI&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=_AerWYGNK8GLvQSdm7bAAg).

Answer (score 0):

First you have forgot `=` equal sign for password here

```
xttp.open("GET", "tst1.php?name="+name+"& password="+password, true);
xttp.send();
```

Also you should first check request data by `isset` like this

```
$name = isset($_REQUEST["name"]): $_REQUEST["name"] : "";
```

Also change submit button as `button` from `submit` to make ajax work

Comment: thanks , but why should i change submit button , i left action empty , what's the difference ? @user2486

Comment: It will submit the same page