# Adding onclick javascript function to template blocks Python Flask routing

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form and a submit button attached to a JavaScript function that greys out the button on click.

```
<form action="/feedback" method="POST">
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <!-- there are more fields but I omit them for brevity -->
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="feedback-submit" onclick="thanks()">
</form>

<script>
function thanks(){
    var button = document.getElementById("feedback-submit")
    button.value = "Thanks!";
    button.disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

And the `/feedback` endpoint is routed to a Flask function that reads the value from the fieldset.

```
@app.route('/feedback', methods=["POST", "GET"]
def feedback():
    if request.method == "POST":
        logging.info(form['rating'])
        return "Thanks for submitting"
```

It seems like having the `onclick` tag in my submit button makes it so that the `feedback()` function is never reached. When I remove the `onclick` `feedback()` executes normally.

I am just curious as to why this is and if there is any way to still get similar functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, will you please provide feedback for the given answer? Did that work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read about why `onclick` on submit button does not work together [Submit and onclick not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839459/submit-and-onclick-not-working-together)

Here is working solution for you.

In your form just assigned `id=someForm`

```
<form id="someForm" action="/feedback" method="POST">
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <!-- there are more fields but I omit them for brevity -->
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="feedback-submit" onclick="thanks()">
</form>
```

In your script:

```
function thanks(){
    var button = document.getElementById("feedback-submit");
    button.value = "Thanks!";
    button.disabled = true;
    var form = document.getElementById("someForm");
    form.submit();
}
```